# How can I 'reward' a user with points in a special circumstance?

Tags: support, bounties

Recently a user commented on one of my posts, pointing out an issue of redundancy in my code.

As it turns out I've been writing small amounts of unnecessary code (for many years now), and since being prompted to read the documentation properly this knowledge has been a welcome time-saver.

I want to award a bounty to the user but obviously one can't do so on a comment.

What's the appropriate thing to do in this situation? Should I hunt out a particularly good answer this user has posted at some point and award a bounty on that instead? Or is that discouraged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an answer you think it is worthy, then you can offer a bounty for the question being answered.

When you offer a bounty for an existing question, one of the reasons you can choose says:

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

As alternative, if you can write a question that can be helpful to other users, you can write it, and offer a bounty. In this case, it is not said the user you are hoping answers.

As side note, I think that offering a bounty is different from unconditionally up-voting the answers given from a user: With a bounty, the reputation gained from a user is lost from another one.
There could be an issue if a user gives, for example, 5000 points to a user with 10 bounties.

Comment: Thanks, I was just making sure I wasn't doing anything 'wrong'. I've hunted out a particularly good answer and awarded a bounty :)